# JSON/AJAX Issue When Server Session Has Timed Out

Tags: html, ajax, json, struts, tiles

I am making ajax and json calls within my site that has a session timeout of 120 minutes on the server side. After the time has expired and a user tries to make an ajax or json call from a page that has been loaded, the call gets made I just sit there with no responds. I am using a sturts.xml file to handle all my action/url calls and this file has an interceptor that runs with every call that gets made to the server. The interceptor checks if you are logged in and sends you to the login screen if you are not. The problem is that the ajax and json calls will are all set up like below:

*I had to replace all "<" and ">" tags with "(" and ")" since the editor wont show them, so just replace the brackets with ">" and "<"

(action name="someAction" class="ActionClass" method="someMethod")
   (result name="success" type="json")
    (param name="target")result(/param)
        (param name="patterns") -*.class(/param)
   (/result)
(/action)

There is a global result that will be called when the interceptor wants to send you to the login page as specified below:

(result name="login" type="tiles")site.login(/result)

since the interceptor sends back a result of "login" and not "success", the ajax and json calls never receives the result it is expecting and when I look at the responds the browser receives it is the raw html of the page I am expecting to be redirected to. Any other type of server call works and sends you to the login screen if your session has timed out. If i try to make an action call as a regular lin, it will work, but I can't make any ajax or json calls and get it to work. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a bit hackish, but here's what I do in php (not sure what language you're working with):

```
if ($is_ajax_request && $not_logged_in)
{
    exit('<script>top.location="/your_login_uri";</script>');
}
```

The ajax call returns the script tag which will redirect the current page to your login page. Once again not sure if you're using it, but you can [detect ajax requests with php](http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax). This is probably not the best way to do it, but I've been using it for a year or so and it works perfectly every time. Hopefully this will give you some ideas at least.

Readers, please comment if you think this solution is a bad idea and tell me why, I'd like to know because I am using it in all my projects.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention, but I am using Java for my backend and JSP and Javascript for the front end.